# How to send medium and source with ga('send', 'pageview', ...)?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

On some referral links (I cannot modify them), I didn't use the standard:

```
example.com/?utm_source=hey&utm_medium=mymedium&utm_campaign=campaign17
```

but I used the non-standard:

```
example.com/?src=foo
```

Thus, it is not tracked correctly in Google-Analytics. It is displayed as:

```
medium  source
(none)  (direct)
```

So I tried to pass the relevant parameters via a custom Javascript code:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/?utm_source=foo&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test');
```

instead of `ga('send', 'pageview');` at the end of the standard analytics `<script>...</script>` snippet.

Still, it doesn't work: it is displayed as `(none) (direct)` (for example in Analytics' *Realtime > Traffic sources*).

**Question: how to pass a source / medium / campaign name via `ga('send', 'pageview', ...);`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use ga('set', ...) command before ga('send', 'pageview'):

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'foo');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'yourmedium');
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'test');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Or you can use more simple syntax:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview', {'campaignSource': 'foo', 'campaignMedium': 'yourmedium', 'campaignName': 'test'});
```

Field reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#trafficsources

Answer (score 0):

use profile filters to push in the parameter into the source medium fields with no code required.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? As it is, this needs more details to be an answer.

Comment: Please extended answer to help as the author requests in the comment